# KMO calculation for dichotomous variables

Tags: correlation, binary-data, factor-analysis

The phi coefficient is a measure of association for two dichotomous variables, and a Pearson correlation coefficient estimated for two dichotomous variables will return the phi coefficient. According to this, if all my variables in my dataset are dichotomous variables, can I use the Pearson correlation matrix to calculate the KMO value in factor analysis? Thank you!!!!